# How does the method JpaSpecificationExecutor<T>.findAll(Specification<T> spec) works?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, crud, criteria-api

I have just a question about the function of the interface

```
JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> findAll(Specification<T> spec).
```

I was wandering how does it internally works? 
Does it retrieves all the raws from the data base and then filters the list?
Or it builds internal a query using the Criteria in the Specification?

Comment: It does the latter. I'm pretty sure you can easily find it in the docs

Comment: Check the [code}(https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L432) it is all in there and as it is Open Source...